# sqlite3 error while moving dataf from csv to database,

Tags: python, sqlite

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'H:\Downloads\rc_3.csv')
df.to_csv('Users.csv', index=False,header=True)
with open('Users.csv','r') as files:
    n=0
    for row in files:
        cursor.execute("Insert into trial(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", row.split(","))
        connection.commit()
        n=0
connection.close()
```

it shows "OperationalError: near "?": syntax error "

the heading of the data looks like this, "Interval"|"ms"|0|0|1,"Utc"|"ms"|0|0|1,"FR"|""|0.0|5.0|25,"Rack"|""|0.0|5.0|25,
initially i thought heading is creating the problem, but..

i am running sqlite3 in python3 jupyternotebook
trial is tables name, and looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trial (
   TimeMS int Primary key,
   Utc int,
   FR Decimal(8,6),
   Rack Decimal(8,5),
   FL Decimal(8,6),
   RR Decimal(8,6),
   RL Decimal(8,6),
   Powerr Decimal(8,5),
   BatteryVolts Decimal(6,4),
   AccelX Decimal(6,4),
   AccelY Decimal(6,4),
   AccelZ Decimal(6,4),
   Yaw Decimal(6,4),
   Pitch Decimal(6,4),
   Roll Decimal(6,4) ,
   GPIO2 int
   
);
```

i am new to sqlite :)

Comment: is pipe the separator or comma in record ?

Comment: if comma is the separator, record has just 6 fields

Comment: i am getting lots of such errors

Comment: pipe is not separator

Comment: basically no of fields in the row should be equal to the number of `?` in the insert statement.

Comment: insert statement is wrong. it should be "insert into trials values(?,?,?,....)". You are missing values keyword.

Comment: yaa,  no is 16  6489603,0,3.046757,1.636501,2.456008,1.920563,4.571393,4.566365,3.9432,0.01,-0.01,0.99,0,0,-0,0         this is how data looks

Comment: then correct the insert statement.

Comment: yaa thanks i was misssing values keyword, but now it says  "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement"   does that mean there is mismatch in no os ? and table columns

Comment: yes.. you are correct

Comment: yaa thanks @RajatMishra its solved now  thanks

Comment: Why are you dumping your data frame to csv and then reading that? Why not insert data directly?

Comment: Also read https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid and https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html